# Qué función tiene un nodo en las etiquetas personalizadas de django?

Tags: django, google-maps, template

Estoy complementando un paquete para `Wagtail` que agrega la opción de usar `Google Maps` y para ello aplica la librería `maps` sobre un campo de texto.

El problema viene cuando intento crear una etiqueta personalizada que permita construir un mapa en las plantillas usando el campo que guarda la dirección del punto a renderizar en el mapa.

Me he inspirado en las [etiquetas](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video/blob/master/embed_video/templatetags/embed_video_tags.py) para mostrar en pantalla videos del paquete `django-embed-videos`.

He visto que el funcionamiento de la etiqueta se basa en usar Nodos, pero no entiendo para que se usan ni por qué. Alguien me puede explicar?

Hasta el momento este es el código que he adaptado:

```
@register.tag('gmap')
class GMapNode(Node):
    """
    Template tag ``gmap``.
    Usage (shortcut):
    .. code-block:: html+django
        {% gmap ADDRESS [ZOOM] [SIZE] [key1=value1, key2=value2...] %}
    Or as a block:
    .. code-block:: html+django
        {% gmap ADDRESS [SIZE] [key1=value1, key2=value2...] as VAR %}
            ...
        {% endgmap %}
    Examples:
    .. code-block:: html+django
        {% gmpa item.gmap %}
        {% gmap item.gmap "large" %}
        {% gmap item.gmap "340x200" %}
    """
    error_msg = 'Syntax error. Expected: ``{% gmap ADDRESS ' \
                '[size] [key1=val1 key2=val2 ...] [as var] %}``'
    default_size = 'small'
    default_zoom = 8

    re_size = re.compile('[\'"]?(?P<width>\d+%?) *x *(?P<height>\d+%?)[\'"]?')

    def __init__(self, parser, token):
        """
        :param parser: Django template parser
        :type parser: django.template.base.Parser
        :param token: Django template token
        :type token: django.template.base.Token
        """
        self.parser = parser
        self.bits = list(token.split_contents())
        self.tag_name = str(self.pop_bit())
        self.address = self.pop_bit()

        if len(self.bits) > 1 and self.bits[-2] == 'as':
            del self.bits[-2]
            self.variable_name = str(self.pop_bit(-1))
            self.nodelist_file = parser.parse(('end' + self.tag_name,))
            parser.delete_first_token()
        else:
            self.variable_name = None

        self.size = self.pop_bit() if self.bits and '=' not in self.bits[0] else None
        self.options = self.parse_options(self.bits)

    def render(self, context):
        """
        Returns generated HTML.
        :param context: Django template RequestContext
        :type context: django.template.RequestContext
        :return: Rendered HTML with embed video.
        :rtype: django.utils.safestring.SafeText | str
        """
        address = self.address.resolve(context)
        zoom = self.zoom.resolve(context)
        size = self.size.resolve(context) if self.size else None
        # options = self.resolve_options(context)

        try:
            return self.render_block(context)

        except requests.Timeout:
            logger.exception('Timeout reached during rendering Google Map (`{0}`)'.format(address))

        return ''

    def render_block(self, context):
        """
        :param context: Django template RequestContext
        :type context: django.template.RequestContext
        :param backend: Given instance inherited from VideoBackend
        :type backend: VideoBackend
        :rtype: django.utils.safestring.SafeText
        """
        context.push()
        output = self.nodelist_file.render(context)
        context.pop()

        return output

    @classmethod
    def get_size(cls, value):
        """
        Predefined sizes:
        ======== ======== =========
        size     width    height
        ======== ======== =========
        tiny     420      315
        small    480      360
        medium   640      480
        large    960      720
        huge     1280     960
        ======== ======== =========
        You can also use custom size - in format ``WIDTHxHEIGHT``
        (eg. ``500x400``).
        :type value: str
        :return: Returns tuple with (width, height) values.
        :rtype: tuple[int, int]
        """
        sizes = {
            'tiny': (420, 315),
            'small': (480, 360),
            'medium': (640, 480),
            'large': (960, 720),
            'huge': (1280, 960),
        }

        value = value or cls.default_size
        if value in sizes:
            return sizes[value]

        try:
            size = cls.re_size.match(value)
            return size.group('width'), size.group('height')
        except AttributeError:
            raise TemplateSyntaxError(
                'Incorrect size.\nPossible format is WIDTHxHEIGHT or using '
                'predefined size ({sizes}).'.format(sizes=', '.join(sizes.keys()))
            )

    def __iter__(self):
        for node in self.nodelist_file:
            yield node

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<GMapNode "%s">' % self.address
```

Como ven, estoy perdido, la idea es imprimir en pantalla un elemento `div` que funcione con el código javascript para que muestre el mapa, algo como:

```
        <div id="map-canvas-{{ map_id }}" {% if width %}style="width: {{ width }}{{ width_units }}; height: {{ height }}{{ height_units }};"{% endif %} class="map-googlemap">
            <noscript>
                <img src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={{ address }}&zoom={{ zoom }}&size={{ width }}x{{ height }}&sensor=false">
            </noscript>
        </div>
```

Tal como especifiqué en la documentación dentro del código la idea es usar la etiqueta con el valor obligatorio dirreción, y los valores opcionales aumento, altura y longitud para imprimir en pantalla un bonito mapa de google.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta es muy amplia. Lo que necesitas es una dirección (latitud y longitud) pero mandas un Node. Deberías empezar con eso. ¿De dónde sale el nodo? ¿Por qué no empiezas enviando una dirección a tu etiqueta?

Comment: Pues por eso mismo, no tengo idea de por que envían un nodo, pero la etiqueta en el otro paquete usa nodos, en cierto momento le pasa la dirección, le pasa un tamaño que obtiene de los parámetros adicionales, pero no entiendo bien como funciona el mecanismo.